# firebase database not returning or displaying newly created collections

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

Hi i have been trying to follow the tutorial in creating an app using firebase. However, i am unable to view the collection once i have entered the various field.

1. The save button is disabled even when i have multiple fields filled out and document id is blank... I have to click autoId and then it becomes enable.
2. Even if i click save, i am unable to view the collection.....anyone know what permission i need to set?

Here is my current rule

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {

// This rule allows anyone with your database reference to view, edit,
// and delete all data in your Firestore database. It is useful for getting
// started, but it is configured to expire after 30 days because it
// leaves your app open to attackers. At that time, all client
// requests to your Firestore database will be denied.
//
// Make sure to write security rules for your app before that time, or else
// all client requests to your Firestore database will be denied until you Update
// your rules
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if request.time < timestamp.date(2020, 8, 29);
  }
 }
}
```

[image: All i have been trying to follow a tutorial using firebase for the first time and for some reason i do not or cannot create collection]

here when i entered some fields without hitting auto-generate id, it will remain disabled....

[image]

Answer (score 4):

They recently changed this, I think - you now have to hit "Auto-ID" to generate the ID *before* saving.  Previously it had automatically done it when you hit Save.  I don't think the tutorial has been updated to reflect this.   This should create the collection and the first document.  There is no "table" - this is NoSQL -there is a collection with a document in it

Comment: Thank you, even though i did this, it never creates the table for me... i cannot see it